# BPF / XDP: 'bpftool batch file' returns 'Error: reading batch file failed: Operation not permitted'

Tags: ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

I have a docker container with an XDP program loaded on it. I also have a batch file for the `bpftool` to run. When I run `bpftool batch file tmp_bpftool.txt`, I get `Error: reading batch file failed: Operation not permitted`. I am the root in the container. So, what could possibly be the problem?

The batch file is as below: (512 updates on map 59 and 1 update on map 58)

```sh
map update id 59 key 0 0 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0 0 0 0 0 4 00 00 
map update id 59 key 1 0 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0 0 0 0 0 4 00 00
.
.
.
map update id 59 key 255 0 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0 0 0 0 0 4 00 00 
map update id 59 key 0 1 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0 0 0 0 0 4 00 00
map update id 59 key 1 1 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0 0 0 0 0 4 00 00
.
. // All the way down to ... (512 entries for id 59)
.
map update id 59 key 254 1 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0 0 0 0 0 4 00 00 
map update id 59 key 255 1 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0 0 0 0 0 4 00 00 
map update id 58 key 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 value 0 0 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Here is the output of the `strace bpftool batch file` command:

```
execve("/usr/sbin/bpftool", ["bpftool", "batch", "file", "tmp_bpftool.txt"], 0x7fffdb7d3a98 /* 9 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558ee931c000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffd7cb85610) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13993, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 13993, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c69f000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\346\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=192032, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4c69d000
mmap(NULL, 194944, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c66d000
mmap(0x7f9c4c67b000, 61440, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe000) = 0x7f9c4c67b000
mmap(0x7f9c4c68a000, 57344, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1d000) = 0x7f9c4c68a000
mmap(0x7f9c4c698000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2a000) = 0x7f9c4c698000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \22\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18816, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 20752, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c667000
mmap(0x7f9c4c668000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f9c4c668000
mmap(0x7f9c4c66a000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f9c4c66a000
mmap(0x7f9c4c66b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f9c4c66b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360A\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\237\333t\347\262\27\320l\223\27*\202C\370T\177"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029560, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\237\333t\347\262\27\320l\223\27*\202C\370T\177"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2037344, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c475000
mmap(0x7f9c4c497000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7f9c4c497000
mmap(0x7f9c4c60f000, 319488, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19a000) = 0x7f9c4c60f000
mmap(0x7f9c4c65d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f9c4c65d000
mmap(0x7f9c4c663000, 13920, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4c663000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4c472000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f9c4c472740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c65d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c66b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c698000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x558ee85e3000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c6d0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f9c4c69f000, 13993)           = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558ee931c000
brk(0x558ee933d000)                     = 0x558ee933d000
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
ioctl(-1, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7ffd7cb85464)    = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
sysinfo({uptime=1021, loads=[43680, 55104, 39616], totalram=8066469888, freeram=1033973760, sharedram=594358272, bufferram=135041024, totalswap=2147479552, freeswap=2147479552, procs=1331, totalhigh=0, freehigh=0, mem_unit=1}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="balancer", ...}) = 0
stat("/xdp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/xdp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getpid()                                = 177
getppid()                               = 174
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=494, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 494
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13993, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 13993, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c69f000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3005\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=51832, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 79672, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c45e000
mmap(0x7f9c4c461000, 28672, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f9c4c461000
mmap(0x7f9c4c468000, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa000) = 0x7f9c4c468000
mmap(0x7f9c4c46a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xb000) = 0x7f9c4c46a000
mmap(0x7f9c4c46c000, 22328, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4c46c000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c46a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f9c4c69f000, 13993)           = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=976, ...}) = 0
read(3, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 976
close(3)                                = 0
getpid()                                = 177
getpgrp()                               = 174
ioctl(2, TIOCGPGRP, [174])              = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x558ee8529aa0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, NULL, {rlim_cur=30509, rlim_max=30509}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/sbin/bpftool", O_RDONLY) = 3
stat("/usr/sbin/bpftool", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1622, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd7cb853f0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(3, "#!/bin/bash\nfull_version=`uname "..., 80) = 80
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, NULL, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=512*1024}) = 0
fcntl(255, F_GETFD)                     = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
dup2(3, 255)                            = 255
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(255, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
fcntl(255, F_GETFL)                     = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(255, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1622, ...}) = 0
lseek(255, 0, SEEK_CUR)                 = 0
read(255, "#!/bin/bash\nfull_version=`uname "..., 1622) = 1622
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
lseek(255, -1586, SEEK_CUR)             = 36
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f9c4c472a10) = 178
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x558ee8529aa0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=0x558ee8529aa0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "5.13.0-35-generic\n", 128)     = 18
read(3, "", 128)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=178, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 178
wait4(-1, 0x7ffd7cb847d0, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x558ee8526480, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=0x558ee8526480, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
read(255, "\n# First check for a fully quali"..., 1622) = 1586
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
lseek(255, -1484, SEEK_CUR)             = 138
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f9c4c472a10) = 179
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x558ee8529aa0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=0x558ee8529aa0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "bpftool\n", 128)               = 8
read(3, "", 128)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=179, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 179
wait4(-1, 0x7ffd7cb84710, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x558ee8526480, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=0x558ee8526480, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
read(255, "if [ -f \"$this\" ]; then\n\texec \"$"..., 1622) = 1484
stat("/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-35-generic/bpftool", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1650632, ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, {sa_handler=0x558ee8529aa0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f9c4c4b80c0}, 8) = 0
lseek(255, -1438, SEEK_CUR)             = 184
execve("/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-35-generic/bpftool", ["/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-35-g"..., "batch", "file", "tmp_bpftool.txt"], 0x558ee9325940 /* 8 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x556ccae20000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffd8177b850) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13993, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 13993, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c039c5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\2005\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=109200, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c039c3000
mmap(NULL, 110976, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c039a7000
mmap(0x7f9c039aa000, 73728, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f9c039aa000
mmap(0x7f9c039bc000, 20480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7f9c039bc000
mmap(0x7f9c039c1000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7f9c039c1000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=108936, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 110776, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c0398b000
mprotect(0x7f9c0398d000, 98304, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c0398d000, 69632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f9c0398d000
mmap(0x7f9c0399e000, 24576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13000) = 0x7f9c0399e000
mmap(0x7f9c039a5000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7f9c039a5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300#\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31120, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 33112, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c03982000
mprotect(0x7f9c03984000, 20480, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c03984000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f9c03984000
mmap(0x7f9c03987000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7f9c03987000
mmap(0x7f9c03989000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f9c03989000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360A\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\237\333t\347\262\27\320l\223\27*\202C\370T\177"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029560, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\237\333t\347\262\27\320l\223\27*\202C\370T\177"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2037344, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c03790000
mmap(0x7f9c037b2000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7f9c037b2000
mmap(0x7f9c0392a000, 319488, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19a000) = 0x7f9c0392a000
mmap(0x7f9c03978000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f9c03978000
mmap(0x7f9c0397e000, 13920, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c0397e000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c0378e000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f9c0378eb80) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c03978000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c03989000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c039a5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c039c1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x556cc8e27000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c039f6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f9c039c5000, 13993)           = 0
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_MAC_OVERRIDE) = 1
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x30 /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x28 /* CAP_??? */) = 0
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x2c /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x2a /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x29 /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x556ccae20000
brk(0x556ccae41000)                     = 0x556ccae41000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "tmp_bpftool.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=70140, ...}) = 0
read(3, "map update id 15 key 0 0 00 00 0"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0 1"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "0 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, " 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 "..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00 0"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "0 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, " 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0 "..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "d 15 key 210 0 00 00 00 00 00 00"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, " \nmap update id 15 key 240 0 00 "..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "te id 15 key 14 1 00 00 00 00 00"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "1 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 0"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, " 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 "..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "0 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 00 00 00 00 00"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, " 00 00 value 10 0 0 1 10 89 0 4 "..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, " 1 00 00 00 00 00 00 value 10 0 "..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, " id 15 key 194 1 00 00 00 00 00 "..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "00 \nmap update id 15 key 224 1 0"..., 4096) = 4096
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, " 0 0 0 0 6 00 00 \nmap update id "..., 4096) = 508
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=15, next_id=0, open_flags=0}, 120) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=80, info=0x7ffd81753730}}, 120) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0x556ccae21490, value=0x556ccae214b0, flags=BPF_ANY}, 120) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
write(2, "Error: ", 7)                  = 7
write(2, "reading batch file failed: Opera"..., 50) = 50
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(-1)                          = ?
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

Comment: Could you share the strace output of that command?

Comment: I added the strace output of the execution above. At the end, there is a `read(3, "", 4096)` that I think fails. My batch file ends in `\n`. Could this ending `\n` be the problem? What is the deal with `operation not permitted`? @pchaigno

Comment: The easiest way to know is to remove it and try again, no?

Comment: I did try that. It wasn't the answer. @pchaigno

Comment: Do you mean removing the newline didn't solve the issue?

Comment: Could you share what the strace output looks like without that newline?

Comment: I don't think the `read()` fails, more likely it's one of the steps during your map updates which sets `errno` to non-0 (and non-`ENOENT`), and this would raise this error _after_ the batch file has been fully processed. This doesn't necessarily mean that your map updates failed by the way, it's maybe just a bug in bpftool where we forgot to reset `errno` where we should have. Are your maps updated as you would expect after running the batch commands, or did it fail in the middle? If the updates didn't go through it might be interesting to know at what step it stopped.

Comment: Yeah. It's pretty much the same thing. @pchaigno

Comment: Yeah. It's pretty much the same thing without the newline. Interesting insights @Qeole, thanks. It seems that the map updates have fully been performed as I checked. All of my bpftool instructions in the batch file are of the same type and kind pretty much, so, I'm guessing that if any single one of them is supposed to set `errno` to non-0, it should be all of them.

Comment: So, what you're saying is, it doesn't have anything to do with the `Operation not permitted` error, and that just comes up because of the `errno` that gets set to its corresponding error number somehow. @Qeole

Comment: Good! Any chance you can check if it does the same with e.g. just one or a few entries in the batch file? Would be awesome to pin down what's setting `errno`, so we can fix it upstream!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Your map update works fine. The message is a bug in bpftool.**

Bpftool updates the maps just as you would expect; and then, after processing all the batch file, it checks `errno`. If `errno` is 0, it supposes that everything went fine, and it's good. If not, it prints `strerror(errno)` so you can see what went wrong when processing the file.

`errno` being set is not due to your map updates. I'm not entirely sure of what's happening to it. The bug was seemingly introduced with [commit cf9bf714523d ("tools: bpftool: Allow unprivileged users to probe features")](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=cf9bf714523dbbc97953be6de6ca14d57d4f8a21), where we manipulate process capabilities with libcap. Having a call to `cap_get_proc()` in feature.c is apparently enough for the executable to pick it up and to run some checks on capabilities that are supported, or not, on the system even if we're not doing any probing. I'm observing the following calls with `strace`:

```
# strace -e prctl ./bpftool batch file /tmp/batch
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_MAC_OVERRIDE) = 1
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x30 /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_CHECKPOINT_RESTORE) = 1
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x2c /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x2a /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x29 /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
Error: reading batch file failed: Operation not permitted
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

This seems to be coming from [`cap_get_bound()` in libcap](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/libcap/cap_proc.c?h=v1.2.63#n272), where the `-1` returned is negated and passed to `errno`, thus becoming `1`, `Operation not permitted`. I'm not sure what the capability numbers passed to `prctl()` correspond to.

I'm not sure what's the cleanest way to fix this. A simple workaround consists in resetting `errno` at the beginning of the `main()` function; we can submit that and see if the reviewers have a better idea. Let me know if you would like to send a patch yourself, otherwise I'll do it when I have a moment.

**[EDIT August 2022]** [Fixed in libcap 2.63](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/commit/?id=f25a1b7e69f7b33e6afb58b3e38f3450b7d2d9a0) and also [in bpf-next for bpftool](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/166058881422.31254.5887784010573260506.git-patchwork-notify@kernel.org/T/#t).

Comment: I think the neat way around this would be to align the error codes returned from `prctl()` with `errno` as you mentioned. The error that happens with `prctl` seems to be an `Invalid argument`, am I right? Is there anything wrong with the provided arguments to `prctl()`?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure, to me it looks like the highest value currently supported by the kernel would be `0x28` (`40`), [from this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/include/uapi/linux/capability.h#L420). So I don't really know what the calls with higher values correspond to. So yeah, I guess ideally `cap_get_bound()` shouldn't set `errno` from the return value, which according to `prctl`'s man page is always `-1` on error. Maybe worth sending something to libcap in that case, although we're still likely to need a fix in bpftool unless we get rid of those failing calls.

Comment: [Fixed in libcap 2.63](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/commit/?id=f25a1b7e69f7b33e6afb58b3e38f3450b7d2d9a0) and also [in bpf-next for bpftool](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/166058881422.31254.5887784010573260506.git-patchwork-notify@kernel.org/T/#t).